# "have been" versus "had been" in questions

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, conditionals, past-perfect, conditional-perfect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do the tenses in English correspond temporally to one another?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/how-do-the-tenses-in-english-correspond-temporally-to-one-another)

"I can tell that he's not English, but I wouldn't had been able to tell that he's french if you didn't tell me first"

it was told me that this kind of usage is wrong, and that I should have used "I wouldn't have been able to tell that"

When should I use "had been" and when "have been"?

Comment: The question is too broad. I can tell you why you shouldn't use _had_ in this example, but that's very far from telling you when you should use _had been_ and when _have been_. There's no single rule for that.

Comment: The reason, by the way, is that _should_ is a [Modal Auxiliary Verb](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/modal.html), and modal auxiliary verbs must be followed by the **Infinitive form** of the next verb. _Had_ is **not** an infinitive form. _Have_ **is** an infinitive form. That's all.

Comment: did you mean _would_ ?

Comment: Yes, quite right. Thanks. They're all modals, and they all have to be followed by an infinitive.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

"have been" is the past perfect tense. It refers to an event in the past, from the perspective of the present. For instance, "*[At some point before NOW]* I have been told he's French".

"had been" is the pluperfect tense. You'd use it when talking about an event in the past that was *before* some other point in the past, say "Before I met him, I had been told he's French".

However, in your case it's actually a different beast, the conditional perfect tense. "would have been" is used whenever there's a condition that existed in the past, whether or not you'd ordinarily use "have been" or "had been".

Basically, the fact you're using a condition overrides the fact that you'd ordinarily use the pluperfect.

Comment: ‘Have been’ is not the past perfect tense. It is a present perfect construction. ‘Had been’ is not the pluperfect tense, but a past perfect construction. There is no such thing in English as the 'conditional perfect tense'.